# 'describe' is skipped when using await

Tags: loops, asynchronous, async-await, mocha.js

The second level describe gets skipped in the report on using await inside it.

I have a test structure where I read files asynchronously in multiple levels in my test and use the data for validation.

This is an oversimplified version of my code so kindly excuse that.
The idea is of making multiple asynchronous calls to read files at multiple level in the test.

```
const { expect } = require('chai');

const subList1 = [
  { title: 'subList1_title1', value: '1' },
  { title: 'subList1_title2', value: '2' },
  { title: 'subList1_title3', value: '3' },
];
const subList2 = [
  { title: 'subList2_title1', value: '1' },
  { title: 'subList2_title2', value: '2' },
  { title: 'subList2_title3', value: '3' },
];

const masterList = [
  {
    title: 'subList1',
    value() {
      return subList1;
    },
  },
  {
    title: 'subList2',
    value() {
      return subList2;
    },
  },
];

function getMasterList() {
  return masterList;
}

describe('All Tests', async function () {
  let testMasterList = [];
  testMasterList = await getMasterList();
  testMasterList.forEach(function (item) {
    describe(item.title, async function () {
      const list = await item.value();
      list.forEach(function (element) {
        describe(element.title, function () {
          it('Value should be a string', function () {
            expect(element.value).to.be.a('string');
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
setTimeout(function () {
  run();
}, 1000);
```

I use the --delay flag with mocha to run the test.

If I remove the 2nd `await` then all the describes are printed in the console.

Expected:

```
  subList1
    subList1_title1
      ✓ Value should be a string
    subList1_title2
      ✓ Value should be a string
    subList1_title3
      ✓ Value should be a string

  subList2
    subList2_title1
      ✓ Value should be a string
    subList2_title2
      ✓ Value should be a string
    subList2_title3
      ✓ Value should be a string
```

Actual:

```
subList1_title1
    ✓ Value should be a string

  subList1_title2
    ✓ Value should be a string

  subList1_title3
    ✓ Value should be a string

  subList2_title1
    ✓ Value should be a string

  subList2_title2
    ✓ Value should be a string

  subList2_title3
    ✓ Value should be a string
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [mocha gitter](https://gitter.im/mochajs/mocha) again, I tried to answer your question there. The issue is in dynamic suite/test generation: you need to first retrieve all data required to *generate* the tests, so if a test or suite has a variable in the name, it needs upfront loading. Alternatively, if you define the tests statically, then you can load async data in hooks or within the tests themselves. Here's the [pen](https://codepen.io/brian-lagerman/pen/WBMwyQ) for you.

```
// Load all data required for suite/test generation first
getMasterList()
  .then(function(testMasterList) {
    testMasterList.forEach(async function(item) {
      item.loaded = await item.value();
    })
    return testMasterList;
  })
  .then(function(testMasterList) {

    describe('All Tests', function () { // Describe is not async, ever...

      testMasterList.forEach(function(item) {
        describe(item.title, function() {
          const list = item.loaded; // Loaded previously in promise form
          list.forEach(function(element) {
            describe(element.title, function() {
              it('Value should be a string', function() {
                chai.expect(element.value).to.be.a('string');
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
```